# How to match two arrays and change color where an element id matches another id in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have two dynamically generated passion arrays from NodeJS MongoDB and socket.io server and I know the source may not be important but:

passions1:

```
[{_id: '60a1557f0b4f226732c4597b', name: 'Netflix'},
{_id: '60a1557f0b4f226732c45980', name: 'Music'},
{_id: '60a1557f0b4f226732c45991', name: 'Hiking'}]
```

passions2:

```
[{_id: '60a4457fr54646647888876d', name: 'Cooking'},
{_id: '60a1557f0b4f226732c4597b', name: 'Netflix'},
{_id: '60a1557f0b4f226732c45997', name: 'Swimming'}]
```

Using naked eyes one can tell that the object `{_id: '60a1557f0b4f226732c4597b', name: 'Netflix'}` exists on both arrays

How do you output or recreate a new array with the existing objects e.g Netflix in bold using angular?

My code:

```
<div *ngFor="let passion of passions1">
<span>{{passion.name}}<span>
<!--
I'm stuck here ..... 
<span *ngIf="passion.name === passion[]">{{passion.name}}<span>
 -->
</div>
```

Any answer typescript / JavaScript would be of great help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly, you basically want to display the value of `name` property in bold if it matches with a value in the `passion` array, right?

Comment: @thisdotutkarsh Correct that's exactly what i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `NgStyle` directive for achieving this in the following way,

In your component.html file,

```html
<div *ngFor="let passion of passionObject">
    <span [ngStyle]="{'font-weight': getFontWeight(passion.name)}">{{passion.name}}</span>
</div>
```

In your component.ts file,
define function `getFontWeight` that accepts a single parameter of type string as follows,

```js
getFontWeight(passionName) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.arrayOfPassions.length; i++) {
      if (passionName === this.arrayOfPassions[i]['name']) {
        return 'bold';
      }
    }
    return 'normal';
  }
```

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gnwtwa?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's better for Angular performance to not call methods from the template, [explained here](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496). In short, your template method is going to be re-run on every change detection.

In Angular, Pipes are pure, meaning they don't get re-run unless their inputs change. The pipe would be pretty simple:

```js
import {
  Pipe,
  PipeTransform
} from '@angular/core';
interface PassionObj {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
}

@Pipe({
  name: 'boldCommonInterests'
})
export class BoldCommonInterestsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(passion: string, passion2Arr: PassionObj[]): boolean {
    return passion2Arr.some(el => el.name === passion);
  }
}
```

And then the template would be:

```html
<div *ngFor="let passion of passions1">
  <span [class.bold-passion]="passion.name | boldCommonInterests: passions2"
    >{{passion.name}}
  </span>
</div>
```

[Stackblitz here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v12-twh4xs?file=src/app/app.component.ts)